# Are covalent crystal compounds with lone electron pairs electrically conductive?

Tags: conductors

In molecular compounds valence electrons can pair up and satisfy each other such as with carbon where the electron configuration is like the following but each electron is paired up with another carbon's electron.

$$ \underset{sp^3}{[\uparrow \vert \uparrow \vert \uparrow \vert \uparrow]} $$

In these compounds the electrons are locked in place in their bonds very strongly.

However, in some compounds such as phosphorous the valence electrons are distributed differently.

An isolated phosphorous atom has a valence configuration like this.

$$ \underset{3s}{[\uparrow \downarrow]} \underset{3p}{[\uparrow \vert \; \vert \uparrow \vert \uparrow]} $$

I think black phosphorous has 3 bonds on each molecule and so I think should have $sp^2$ hybridization and I think has a valence electron configuration of

$$ \underset{(3s)(3p)^2}{[\uparrow \vert \uparrow \vert \uparrow ]} \underset{3p}{[\uparrow \downarrow]} $$

or

$$ \underset{(3s)(3p)^3}{[\uparrow \downarrow \vert \uparrow \vert \uparrow \vert \uparrow ]} $$

Black phosphorous is flaky and planar (sort of like a bunch of connected trigonal planar molecules) and so this seems right to me.

Black phosphorous is electrically conductive. Is black phosphorous electrically conductive because the phosphorous atoms are relatively close to each other and because there is a free lone electron pair that can be easily ionized off and then swapped around the phosphorous atoms?

Are all covalent crystal compounds with lone electron pairs (or I guess lone electrons work too) electrically conductive? Can one engineer compounds with a great deal of lone electron pairs? I would think that period 4 and above elements which could have a bunch of d orbital lone electron pair should be electrically conductive but I have read that s and p orbitals are taken off first in chemical reactions and so should be taken off before electrically too.